# Problema al usar ALIAS en SQL en ACCESS

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, ms-access

lo que sucede es que estoy iniciando con SQL y lo manejo en ACCESS y al usar el alias como lo propone la actividad me da un error

```
SELECT A1.Store_Name Store, SUM(A1.Sales) "Total Sales" 
FROM Store_Information A1 GROUP BY A1.Store_Name;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es:
[image: mensaje de error]

Comment: Esto desde un celular es ilegible y dispendioso para poder ver el código y el error. si eligieras compartir elcódigo como texto, sería más fácil

Comment: SELECT A1.Store_Name Store, SUM(A1.Sales) "Total Sales"
FROM Store_Information A1
GROUP BY A1.Store_Name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [documentación](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-SQL-FROM-clause-2A7D031C-6912-4E8C-A644-590940DDAED1) dice que el alias se especifica usando AS

```
SELECT 
[A1].[Store_Name Store], SUM(A1.Sales) "Total Sales" 
FROM [Store_Information] AS [A1] 
GROUP BY [A1].[Store_Name];
```